# Find the relation between $x$ and $y$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE.$$dx/dt=-2y-x\sin (xy)$$ and $$dy/dt=2x+y\sin (xy)$$Find the relation between $x$ and $y$

My try:$$ydx/dt=-2y^2-xy\sin (xy)$$and $$xdy/dt=2x^2+xy\sin (xy)$$.Now adding, We get $\frac{d(xy)}{dt}=2(x^2-y^2)$.But how to proceed next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing the equations
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2\,x+y\sin(x\,y)}{2\,y+x\sin(x\,y)},
$$
or
$$
(2\,x+y\sin(x\,y))\,dx+(2\,y+x\sin(x\,y))\,dy=0.
$$
This is an exact equation.